# Printing Multiple Strings to a File

Tags: c++, string, file

I am working on a phone book, and have so far been successfully able to have the user input their info, save it to a string, save the string to a file, and search for that string using a keyword. However, it only is functional for the first contact that is inputted. When a new contact is inputted, it overwrites the previous string saved in the file. How can I make it print to the next line, and develop a list of contacts that can be searched through. Any help is much appreciated. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

struct person
{
    string Name;
    string Address;
    string PhoneNumber;
    string Email;
};

int main()
{
ResetUserSelection:
    vector<person>ContactList;

    int userselection = 0;

    cout << "Press 1 to Add Contact" << endl;
    cout << "Press 2 to Search for Contact"<<endl;
    cout << "What do you want to do? ";
    cin >> userselection;

    if(userselection == 1)
    {
        person newPerson;

        cout << endl;
        cin.ignore();
        cout << "What is your Name? " ;
        getline(cin,newPerson.Name);

        cout << "What is your Address? " ;
        getline(cin,newPerson.Address);

        cout << "What is your Phone Number? " ;
        getline(cin,newPerson.PhoneNumber);

        cout << "What is your Email? ";
        getline(cin,newPerson.Email);

        cout << endl;

        string fullContact = "Name: " + newPerson.Name + ", Address: " +     newPerson.Address + ", Phone Number: " + newPerson.PhoneNumber + ", Email: " +     newPerson.Email + "\n";

        cout <<fullContact;

        cout << endl;

        ofstream myfile;
        myfile.open ("contactlist.txt");
        myfile << fullContact;
        myfile.close();
        goto ResetUserSelection;

        goto ResetUserSelection;
    }
    else
    {
        string search;

        ifstream Myfile;
        Myfile.open ("contactlist.txt");
        cout << "Who do you want to search for?" << endl;
        cin >> search;
        cout << endl;

        ifstream myfile;
        myfile.open ("contactlist.txt");
        string contact;
        while(getline(myfile, contact))
        {
            if(contact.find(search) != string::npos)
            {
                cout << search << "'s contact info" << endl << contact << endl << endl;
            }
        }
        myfile.close();

        goto ResetUserSelection;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's why people hate `goto`, because some people give it the worst possible use, can't you write a loop?

Answer (score 1):

This line: `myfile.open ("contactlist.txt");` is missing the second parameter, the mode, which should be `app`

`app` means to open for append.  I.E. to add on to the end of the file.

Comment: **Question**: why does the code compile then, is there an overload that ignores the parameter?, does the parameter have a default value?

Comment: Default value: `void open (const char* filename,  ios_base::openmode mode = ios_base::out);`

Comment: @user4581301 use this character `\`` to make the code parts use a monospaced font, which makes them easier to read, and also highlights them by giving them a grey background.

Comment: Thank you. Learn something new every day!

Answer (score 1):

When you open your file for writing, you set the `filepointer` to the start of the file by default. You should add the append option when opening your file.

See the API of [ofstream::open](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/open/) how to do this:

```
myfile.open ("contactlist.txt", ofstream::out | ofstream::app);
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing, include vector since you're using it.
Now, you face this problem because of not giving correct arguments to std::fstream::open, so it overwrites previous contents.

Replace

```
    myfile.open ("contactlist.txt");
```

with

```
    myfile.open ("contactlist.txt",std::fstream::out|std::fstream::app);
```

and it should work. For more details, http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/fstream/open/